# Entity Framework one to many relation code first

Tags: entity-framework, one-to-many, relationship

I am having my first steps in EF 4.1. Because I was using NHibenate, the code first approach seems to me as the best one. I have problem with good mapping of one-to-many (or many-to-one) realtionship. Let's say I have 2 entities:

```
class ClientModel
{
    int ClientID;
    string Name;
    virtual IList<OrderModel> Orders;
}

class OrderModel
{
    int OrderID;
    string Details;
    virtual ClienModel Client;
}
```

When I leave it like that, there is an error while generating database - keys in tables are missing. I figured out I can fix it by changing names of the keys to ID (but it's not OK with my naming convention) or by adding [Key] annotation. Even if I add this annotation, still the names of tables are wrong - just like classes names but with 's'.
So I tried to use fluent API - I made mappings. But if I set mappings just like here:

```
class ClientMapping
{
    ClientMapping()
    {
        this.HasKey(e => e.ClientID).Property(e => e.ID).HasColumnName("ClientID");
        this.Property(e => e.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
        this.HasMany(e => e.Orders).WithOptional().Map(p => p.MapKey("OrderID")).WillCascadeOnDelete();
        this.ToTable("Clients");
    }
}

class OrderMapping
{
    OrderMapping()
    {
        this.HasKey(e => e.OrderID).Property(e => e.OrderID).HasColumnName("OrderID");
        this.Property(e => e.Details).HasColumnName("Details");
        this.HasRequired(e => e.Client).WithMany().Map(p=>p.MapKey("Client")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        this.ToTable("Orders");
    }
}
```

the relation betweene tables in database is doubled. 
What is the proper way to do one-to-many relationship using code-first approach? Am I thinking in a good direction or is it a wrong approach?

**EDIT**

OK, I have done it in the way **@Eranga** showed, but there is still a problem. When I'm getting Client from database, its Orders property is null (but in database it has some Orders with Order.ClientID == Client.ClientID).

Comment: I tested the configuration given in my answer and it works fine. Make sure `Orders` is a property not a field.

Comment: Try `virtual List<OrderModel> Orders;` instead of `virtual IList<OrderModel> Orders;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to map both properties participating in the relationship. You need to add `ClientID` column to Orders table.

```
class ClientMapping
{
    ClientMapping()
    {
        this.HasKey(e => e.ClientID).Property(e => e.ID).HasColumnName("ClientID");
        this.Property(e => e.Name).HasColumnName("Name");

        this.HasMany(e => e.Orders).WithRequired(o => o.Client)
           .Map(p => p.MapKey("ClientID")).WillCascadeOnDelete();

        this.ToTable("Clients");
    }
}

class OrderMapping
{
    OrderMapping()
    {
        this.HasKey(e => e.OrderID).Property(e => e.OrderID).HasColumnName("OrderID");
        this.Property(e => e.Details).HasColumnName("Details");
        this.ToTable("Orders");
    }
}
```

Configuring the relationship from one entity is sufficient.

Comment: "You need to map both properties participating in the relationship. You need to add ClientID column to Orders table."
What do you exactly mean by that?

Comment: @rideronthestorm `Orders` property in `ClientModel` and `Client` property in `OrderModel` as the two participants of the relationship.

Comment: I still don't understand it. Wasn't I mapping both of them? Maybe you could post full code for it?
And why do I need ClientID in Orders (OrderModel?)?

Comment: @rideronthestorm I posted the full code for mapping. The way you mapped will be interpreted by EF as two different relationships. Since an `Order` requires a `Client` you need to added the foreign key column `ClientID` to `Order` table

Comment: Isn't ClienModel Client; enough as a foreign key?

Comment: Amd ypu are saying that I should put int ClientID instead of ClientModel Client? Why there is no Client or ClientID mapping?

Comment: And the other question is what is the difference if I set hasMany in client or withMany in order? These are 2 different ways to describe the same relation?

Comment: I did it like you said - so model has no changes, but mappnigs are like the ones you've posted. The database was generated without errors, but there is something wrong with it, because when I try to generate diagram for it in SQl Management Studio, I get the error "The table '<table_name>' no longer exists in the database" for each of my generated tables. However, they are accessible, I can see their columns, modify them, etc.

Comment: @rideronthestorm You do not ned to add `ClientID` property to `OrderModel`. EF will create a column `ClientID` in `Orders` table when you map the entities as I have shown. `HasMany` is used when you map from the **many** side. `WithMany` is used when you map form **one** side of the relationship to the **many** side.

Comment: "HasMany is used when you map from the many side. WithMany is used when you map form one side of the relationship to the many side." - yes, I know that, but what is the difference in effect? In my example could I use withMany in Client instead of hasMany in order and effect (objects generated) would be the same?

Answer (score 0):

This may help (it helped me, when i couldn't figure out how this works):

If you would have the classes like this:

```
class ClientModel
{
    int ClientId;
    string Name;
}

class OrderModel
{
    int OrderId;
    string Details;
    int ClientId;
}
```

Then this would represent 2 tables in your database which "wouldn't" be connected with each other via a foreign key (they would be connected via the `ClientId` in the `OrderModel`) and you could get data like "GetAllOrdersWithSomeClientId" and "GetTheClientNameForSomeClientId" from the database. BUT problems would arise when you would delete a `Client` from the database. Because then there would still be some `Orders` which would contain a `ClientId` which doesn't exist in the `Client` table anymore and that would lead to anomalies in your database.

The `virtual List<OrderModel> Orders;` (in the `ClientModel`) and `virtual ClienModel Client;` (in the `OrderModel`) are needed to create the relation aka. the foreign key between the tables `ClientModel` and `OrderModel`.

There is one thing about which i'm still not sure about. Which is the `int ClientId;` in the `OrderModel`. I guess that it has to have the same name as the `ClientId` in the `ClientModel` so that the entity framework knows which 2 attributes the foreign key has to connect. Would be nice if someone could explain this in detail.

Also, put this into your DbContext constructor if something souldn't work:

```
this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```